# Private property called @this that returns this

Tags: c#, coding-style

I know that prefixing a C# string literal with `@` marks it as a verbatim string literal, but what purpose would this serve if it was prefixed to the name of a private property?

This came up in some code I was maintaining...

```
public class JourneyBuilder
{
    // ...

    private JourneyBuilder @this
    {
        get { return this; }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Can anyone suggest a rationale for this?

### Edit

I guess this is actually two questions (one of which has already been answered). The second is: Why have a private property that just returns `this`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a way of "escaping" a reserved keyword so you can use it as an identifier.  For the most part it is better to simply come up with a different name rather than to use this approach, but the C# compiler does allow this.

On a side note the only place I have seen it used where it makes a bit of sense is when you are naming the instance parameter of an extension method like this:

```
public static void Foo(this Object @this)
{
    // ...
}
```

But even in this case it would be just as good to name the parameter `source` or something equally as indicative of its nature.

As to why you would ever need a *private* property that returns `this`: *there is no reason to ever do it*.  You are only providing a private method to the type for accessing a reference that is already available.  Fortunately, since the member is private, you can easily remove it.

Comment: This can come up when working with libraries created in another language (IIRC this is not a keyword in VB). The CLS rules, however, try to block this by reserving a union of language keyword sets.

Comment: But the second question remains - why have a private property (regardless of name) that just returns this?